# Error in Iteration

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int age, i;
char name[10], address[10]; 
for( i=0; i<3; i++ )
{
     printf("Enter your name: ");
     gets(name);
     printf("Where do you live?");
     gets(address);
     printf("What's your age? ");
     scanf("%d", &age);
 }
```

On the second iteration of the code, execution skips the "Enter your name: " part. Why?

Comment: Don't use `gets` -- it is horribly unsafe, instead use, e.g. `fgets (name, sizeof name, stdin)` This is a prime example of why NOT to use `scanf` for mixed input unless you **account for** all characters left in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`) -- you leave a `'\n'` in the *input buffer* after your call to `scanf("%d", &age);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean it skips?

Comment: Keep in mind that the last scanf doesn't read in the newline, which gets immediately picks up.

Comment: Add a \n to your scanf format string.

Comment: The '\n' is getting stored in the name on the second iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a newline character at the end of entering the age.

I would suggest you to use `fgets()` instead of `gets()` and get rid of newline character after scanning `age`

Consume the `\n` character after reading age by placing a space after `%d`.

```
scanf("%d ",&age);

fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
size_t n = strlen(name);

if(n>0 && name[n-1] == '\n')
{
   name[n-1] = '\0';
}
```

P.S:: There is a newline character at end of `fgets()` so you need to get rid of it.

Comment: What's happening here? The '\n' pressed after age, gets stored in the name?

Comment: In the stdin buffer the `\n` character is stored and it is not read by your `%d`. So once it encounters `%s` as part of reading the name is it consumed and stored in `name`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

to

```
scanf("%d ", &age);
```

So that it reads the white space (new line).

Get rid of `gets` as noted in the comments

Check the return value of `scanf`